# what is the difference between $(\cos A)^2$ and $\cos^2 A$

Tags: trigonometry

$$  (|\cos A|)^2 \qquad\text{and}\qquad \cos^2 A $$

For example if $\cos A = 0.5$, and $0.5 \times 0.5 = 0.25$, are here some difference in the notations or are they equal?

Comment: They're the same.

Comment: If we lived in a perfect world $\cos^2(A)$ would mean $\cos(\cos(A))$ -- but we don't.

Comment: Notation is rarely perfect. But at least the convention of writing $\cos^2 A$ avoids all the extra characters and inelegance of $(\cos A)^2$ or $(|\cos A|)^2$.

Comment: Consistent notation would require writing $(\cos A)^2$, but trigonometry has been developed when functions were not yet really used as nowadays. Since squares of sines and cosines appear very frequently in formulas, people started to used shorthands such as $\cos^2 A$ and now we're stuck with them.

Comment: Yet $cos^{-1}(x) \neq (cos(x))^{-1}$. It's all a mess really.